# c#, GenericRepository,Service Layer

Tags: c#-4.0

I have in class GenericRepository this method :

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
           string includeProperties = "") {...}
```

And in the service layer i have :

```
IAdsRepository _adsRepository;

        public AdsService(IAdsRepository adsRepository)
        {
            _adsRepository= adsRepository;
        }

public IEnumerable<Ads> GetAllAds(....)
         {
             return _adsRepository.GetAll(....);
         }
```

(i have a repository to specify genericRepository )

someone has an idea for how the parameters passed to the method Get() ?

thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter` takes a filter function which takes a TEntity as a parameter and returns a boolean which is true if the entity should be included in the result. For example, `x => x.Value > 7` can be passed to have `Get` return all TEntities with a `Value` greater than 7.

The second parameter takes an IQueryable as a parameter and returns an IOrderedQueryable (ie where sort order is defined) For example `x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Value)` will order the results by `Value`.

For example then;

```
repository.Get( x => x.Value > 7, x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Value));
```

will return all entities with a `Value` greater than 7, ordered by Value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, are there any way  to generalize  my service (GetAll(...)) because in the controller i want to specify the parametters  for GetAll(...)

Comment: @saisne I'm not sure I understand the question, you're not mentioning what GetAll should return or what you want its parameters to be.